# Create message liseners dynamically for the topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I was analysing a problem on creating a generic consumer library  which can be deployed in multiple microservices ( all of them are spring based) . The requirement is to have around 15-20 topics to listen .If we use annotation based kafka listener ,we need to add more code for each microservice . Is there any way where we can create the consumers dynamically based on some xml file where each consumer can have these data injected

1. topic
2. groupid
3. partition
4. filter (if any)

With annotations ,the design is very rigid .The only way I can think of  is ,we can create messagelisteners after parsing xml config  and each topic will have its own concurrentmessagelistenercontainer .

Is there any alternative better approach available using spring ?

P.S: I am little new to spring & kafka . Please let me know if there is confusion in explaning the requirements

Thanks,
Rajasekhar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use topic patterns. Take a look at [consumer properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#container-props). E.g. the listener

```
@KafkaListener(topicPattern = "topic1|topic2")
```

will listen to `topic1` and `topic2`.

If you need to create a listener dynamically extra care must be taken, because you must shutdown it.

I would use a similar approach as spring's [`KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/v2.5.5.RELEASE/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java). This post processor is responsible for processing `@KafkaListener`s.

Here is a proposal of how it could work:

```
public class DynamicEndpointRegistrar {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> containerFactory;
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry endpointRegistry;
    private MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory;

    public DynamicEndpointRegistrar(BeanFactory beanFactory,
            KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> containerFactory,
            KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry endpointRegistry, MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.containerFactory = containerFactory;
        this.endpointRegistry = endpointRegistry;
        this.messageHandlerMethodFactory = messageHandlerMethodFactory;
    }

    public void registerMethodEndpoint(String endpointId, Object bean, Method method, Properties consumerProperties,
            String... topics) throws Exception {
        KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar = new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar();
        registrar.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        registrar.setContainerFactory(containerFactory);
        registrar.setEndpointRegistry(endpointRegistry);
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory);

        MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<Integer, String> endpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
        endpoint.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory);

        endpoint.setId(endpointId);
        endpoint.setGroupId(consumerProperties.getProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG));
        endpoint.setBean(bean);
        endpoint.setMethod(method);

        endpoint.setConsumerProperties(consumerProperties);
        endpoint.setTopics(topics);

        registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
        registrar.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

}
```

You should then be able to register a listener dynamically. E.g.

```
DynamicEndpointRegistrar dynamicEndpointRegistrar = ...;
MyConsumer myConsumer = ...; // create an instance of your consumer
Properties properties = ...; // consumer properties

// the method that should be invoked
// (the method that's normally annotated with KafkaListener)
Method method = MyConsumer.class.getDeclaredMethod("consume", String.class);

dynamicEndpointRegistrar.registerMethodEndpoint("endpointId", myConsumer, method, properties, "topic");
```